# UK visa: unsigned application form

Tags: uk, online-resources, visa-refusals, visa-rejections, applications

I just submitted my UK tourist visa application. However I forgot to sign the printed online form although I made an e-signature after my fingerprints registration. Does this lead to a refusal?

Comment: It will not be refused.  If they decide it's a show-stopper they will reject it; i.e., send it back to the VFS so you can sign it.  It will have a short fuse on it because they do not want your evidence to get stale.  A rejection is not the same as a refusal, so it's not a big problem.

Comment: added 'visa-rejection' tag

Comment: Last time I submitted visa application they said signature is no more required.

Answer (score 5):

**No, your application will not be refused due to the lack of a signature.**

> It will not be refused. If they decide it's a show-stopper they will reject it; i.e., send it back to the VFS so you can sign it. It will have a short fuse on it because they do not want your evidence to get stale. A rejection is not the same as a refusal, so it's not a big problem.

Source: comment on this TSE thread by user Gayot Fow